# How to stop or pause php execution?

Tags: php

I want to do some basic debugging with print_r.

When PHP hits that line I want it to stop or end whatever people usually do, so I can see the output.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
// if you want a one liner:
die(print_r($stuff, true ));
```

You'd really enjoy a [proper debugger](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html) though

Comment: I have it installed and it seems more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Do you mean XDebug or Netbeans? You could try Eclipse instead.

Comment: You've got another killer option called phpStorm. It is not free but believe me it is worth every single penny.

Comment: @Hesam it's free if you got a student card!

Answer (score 7):

For stopping execution in PHP, you have for example **[die](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php)** and **[exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)**.

For advanced debugging, use tools such as [**XDebug**](http://www.xdebug.org/).

Or sleep: `sleep(30);` for a 30 second delay.

Comment: Beware with the sleep function that you'd better to pass only integers to it as it would disregard the decimal part.

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
print_r($whatever);    
exit();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
die("Script Stopped");
```

This will end execution of code and echo the message you put between the quotations - this can be a string or an integer you need to debug, I use it often when debugging.  Half-split works well, put var_dumps halfway through your code, put a die at the end, find which half is going wrong, split that in half, etc, until you get to a point that you can logically guess where the error is and start debugging the syntax/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep it in the family, one file....

```
 if (@$_GET['thispic']){
    dizzy($_GET['thispic']);
    exit;
    }


    function dizzy($thispic){
    $PSize = filesize($thispic);
    $mysqlPicture =  fread(fopen($thispic, "r"), $PSize) ; 
    ///add file type checking here
    Header( "Content-type: image/jpg") ;
    echo $mysqlPicture;
    }


    $Picture = "images/brand.jpg";
    echo "<img src = \"test.php?thispic=$Picture \" height = \"300\">";
```

I use similar script for thumbnails from a database.
to avoid the base64 decoding thus saving load time.

contact: tim@tmgraphics.biz